# Python script in /cgi-bin/ won't execute, but a Perl script will: how can I make the Python script execute?

Tags: python, apache, scripting, cgi

I'm trying to run a basic Python CGI script on my Apache server. I have my `hola.py` script in my `/cgi-bin/` directory, I changed the file's permissions to make it executable, and I changed the owner of the file to the apache user. However, I can't get the Python script to actually run.

I experimented by making a Perl script, and surprisingly it worked fine with the same steps I had followed to make the python script run.

I don't think the problem is in the scripts because I have added the `#!/usr/bin/python` line at the top of the source code and I've successfully executed it from the command line (that is, `./hola.py`), in which case it worked just fine.

It's very strange to me that the Perl script worked where the Python script didn't. I've looked in several places for solutions to this, but haven't found one yet.

I'd be happy to post parts of my `httpd.conf` if anyone needs to see them.

**EDIT:**

Before you tell me to take a look at the `error_log` of the server, there is a line there -

`(13) Permission denied: exec of '/var/www/cgi-bin/hola.py' failed`

Comment: Try reading this: http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html#common-problems-with-cgi-scripts

Comment: Very obvious problems could be - your apache doesn't have any modules included to work with python as CGI, you don't have proper handlers set up, scripts doesn't have execute bits set...

Comment: Modify httpd.conf to have a line like this for cgi scripts. AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py . Restart Apache and see if it helps.

Comment: Be sure to check your python syntax for errors; one way I would recommend to do this is install pylint and run it on your script. Also be sure to check that the script permissions are sound (`chmod +x hola.py`) and that the script is owned by apache2 (or www-data).